# Why doesn't my CSS code turn all the text white in the specified div?

Tags: html, css

I'm diving into web development and CSS is getting the best of me very early on.  I have the following html...

```
<div class="span-6" id="left-sidebar"> 
    <h4>Left Sidebar</h4> 
    <ul> 
        <li>fruits</li> 
        <li>meats</li> 
    </ul> 
    <h4>This is a header</h4> 
</div>
```

and my CSS code...

```
#left-sidebar, #right-sidebar {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

but only the text "fruits" and "meats" are rendered in white text, the other text is rendered is a dark grey color.  Why isn't all the text rendered in white?

Also, I find I can fix this when I'm more specific, using the CSS code...

```
#left-sidebar, #left-sidebar h4,   {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Why do I have to be more specific?  Doesn't #left-sidebar mean, "render all text in the left-sidebar using white, unless it's been overwritten with a more specific CSS statement"?

I should also note that I don't have any other CSS code that's related to the left-sidebar div.  Also, I'm using Blueprint CSS (as you can see in the "span-6" class), but I don't know how that could be conflicting with anything.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Above code is fine... http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/kgDwe/

Comment: You do have something "conflicting" (overriding) the colour, because it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/5tPm7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blueprint css has default colours for heading tags. (see [screen.css](https://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css/blob/master/blueprint/screen.css))

You need to specify:

```
#left-sidebar h2, #left-sidebar h4, 
#right-sidebar h2, #right-sidebar h4 { color: white; }
```

Comment: Or alternately "color: inherit".  Then all <h2>s and <h4>s will have the same color as their containing element whether that color is white or not.

Comment: actually, when I add "h2 {color:white;}" or "h2 {color:inherit}" to my custom.css file, nothing changes, it still maintains the same color defined in the blueprint file.  If I'm including my external custom.css file after the blueprint files, shouldn't the browser accept the last read style definition for h2 (i.e. my "h2 {color:white}" style)?

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe It's best that you use a more specific selector, or !important, as stylesheet order may not be what you expect. I will edit my answer

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe You're welcome! By the way, as long as custom.css loads *after* screen.css, any changes should override what is in custom.css. But I like to use specific selectors in any case, it's more easy to maintain…

Comment: Do you mean, "as long as custom.css loads after screen.css, any changes should override what is in screen.css"?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I understood as well, so I'm confused why adding "h2{color:white;}" to my custom.css file doesn't change anything. I'm taking your advice and using more specific selectors just for good practice, but I'd like to understand what's happening as well. Any ideas?

Comment: What order are the files specified in the HTML?

Comment: <link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/screen.css?1290007256" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/print.css?1290007256" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/stylesheets/blueprint/plugins/fancy-type/screen.css?1290007256" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/stylesheets/custom.css?1300491140" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the h (header) definitions are sometimes pre-set by the browser.  Are you using a CSS reset?  Try this out http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/ - it essentially gets rid of browser defaults and makes it much easier to develop websites across multiple browsers.

In the short term, try setting the definitions of the h2 and h4 individually, like this:

```
h2,h4 {
     color: white;
}
```

Or add an important tag to your current CSS, like such:

```
#left-sidebar, #right-sidebar {
    background-color: black;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Firebug in Firefox or the developer tools in Chrome to see what classes are being applied to each element. You just "Inspect" the element and view the applied CSS rules in the pane on the left.

Answer (score 0):

the header tags need their own CSS Class.

```
h2, h4{
color:white;
}
```

should do the trick